# how to make left take attr value in css?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want the `left` css property to take the value from the html element using `attr` like this

```
<div left-value="30px"/>
div{
left: attr(left-value);
}
```

is this even possible? it works with after and before.

Comment: Currently attr is implemented for most browsers for the content CSS property in pseudo elements. I do not know which browsers support it for other properties in pseudo elements - can you say for which ones it is working for you? Note also if you are introducing your own attribute values then they should start with data- for 'pure' HTML. In any case, to achieve what you want at the moment you will need some JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attr css function is appearently very powerful but yet very limited as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

> Note: The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but
> support for properties other than content is experimental, and support
> for the type-or-unit parameter is sparse.

Anyway there's a trick you can use to get quite the same result but using css custom properties. Instead of defining an attribute on the html element that you are going to read in your css rule using `attr`, you can just set that same value on a custom property using the inline styling. Then in your rule just use that custom property to set the left properrty of the element.

Here I also put a container with position relative, to better highlight the correct working of this solution:

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  border: dashed 4px lightgray;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.container > div{
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--left-value);
  border: solid 1px gray;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="--left-value: 20px;"></div>
</div>
```

Of course it doesn't look very smart to use a custom property instead of using directly the left property since you are using the inline styling already. There are cases when this solution could be the way to go.. but here indeed it's not really changing the game

Answer (score -1):

First-of-all there is no such attribute as left-value in HTML. You have to use pre-build attr in HTML cuzz it's not react. Secondly if you want to left align the  just simply use position and left attr of css or just do some styling using margin-left.

Comment: While you are correct that there is no in-built attribute left-value in HTML5, users may define there own attributes but they should be prefixed with data- for fully correct code. I don't understand your second sentence 'simply use position [yes, that is needed] and left atrr of css [what is left attr of CSS?].